# Sumar valor de un Foreach en controlador MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

necesito sumar el ponderado las veces que se recorra el ciclo y mostrarlo en `builder.Append(total suma ponderados).Append(";");`, mi código es el siguiente:

```
foreach (var item_ponderado in listobjetivos)
 {
   var ponderado = (item_ponderado.p.Peso_Objetivo * item_ponderado.o.calificacion / 100);
   Builder.Append(ponderado).Append(";");
 }
builder.Append(total suma ponderados).Append(";");
```

Me explico, necesito sumar el valor de la variable ponderado las veces que se recorra el ciclo, y pueda guardarlo en una variable por ejemplo `total_ponderados` para mostrarlo en `builder.Append(total suma ponderados).Append(";");` no se si me doy a entender.

Un ejemplo:

La primera vez que se recorrió el ciclo el valor del ponderado fue 0.5 y la segunda vez que se recorrió es 1.5, se guarda el valor 2 en una variable para mostrarlo donde mencione anteriormente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo declaras fuera del foreach como `decimal dTotalPonderado = 0;` en el foreach dentro del ciclo despues de tu `var ponderado = (item_ponderado.p.Peso_Objetivo * item_ponderado.o.calificacion / 100);` podes poner `dTotalPonderado += Convert.ToDecimal(ponderado);` y al final `builder.Append(dTotalPonderado ).Append(";");` y listo vas esa variable dTotalPonderado contendra la sumatoria de todos los ponderados.

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacerlo de la siguiente forma, te dejo el codigo parcial, si no se entiende me avisas:

```
int i =0;
List<decimal> sumatoria = new List<decimal>();
for each....

    if (i>0){
         sumatoria.Add(sumatoria[i-1]+ponderado);
    }else{
         sumatoria.Add(ponderado);
    }
    i+=1;
fin for each...
```

Podria mejorarse el codigo usando un for i en lugar de for each y usar "listobjetivos[i]" en lugar de item_ponderado

Espero te sirva.

Saludos!